# Dividindo em PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, decimal, inteiros, divisão

Estou tentando fazer a select abaixo, mas o resultado da coluna "perc_vol_lei" (na imagem) está errado, ele não pode ser zero.

```
select to_char (tb_esq.datahora, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as data_esq, tb_esq.tick, tb_esq.variacao, tb_esq.quantidade as qtt_26, tb_dir.quantidade as qtt_0,
 (tb_esq.quantidade - tb_dir.quantidade) as volume_no_leilao,
 ((tb_esq.quantidade - tb_dir.quantidade)/tb_esq.quantidade) as perc_vol_lei  

from tb_registros as tb_esq 
     join tb_registros as tb_dir on tb_esq.tick = tb_dir.tick 
        and to_char(tb_esq.datahora,'yyyy-mm-dd') = to_char(tb_dir.datahora,'yyyy-mm-dd')
    
        where (tb_esq.quantidade - tb_dir.quantidade) > 50000 and tb_esq.refer =26 and tb_dir.refer = 0 
                AND tb_esq.tick <>'DOLFUTV' and tb_esq.tick <>'IBOV' and tb_esq.tick <>'WDOFUT'and tb_esq.tick <>'DOLFUT'
order by volume_no_leilao desc`
```

Já alterei a linha da coluna perc_vol_lei para
`((tb_esq.quantidade - tb_dir.quantidade)/tb_esq.quantidade):: double precision as perc_vol_lei` para   `round(((tb_esq.quantidade - tb_dir.quantidade)/tb_esq.quantidade):: decimal, 5) as perc_vol_lei` e para `((tb_esq.quantidade - tb_dir.quantidade)/tb_esq.quantidade):: numeric as perc_vol_lei`, mas o resultado permanece o mesmo.

Alguém consegue me auxiliar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente os seus campos são de algum tipo de número inteiro, então divisão de um número inteiro por outro número inteiro sempre resulta em um número inteiro descartando a parte decimal.

Você vai precisar converter algum destes valores usados na divisão para algum tipo de número decimal, algo do tipo

`((tb_esq.quantidade - tb_dir.quantidade)/ cast(tb_esq.quantidade as float)) as perc_vol_lei`

Repare que não adianta tentar converter para decimal depois de fazer a divisão, você precisa converter pelo menos um dos valores antes de dividir

Comment: Obrigado Leandro. Depois de algumas pesquisas entendi a questão do inteiro. Uma solução que obtive em outro local foi a de colocar o ":: numeric", dentro dos parênteses, ficando como "(..../tb_esq.quantidade:: numeric) as perc_vol_lei". Isso também resolveu meu problema. De todo modo, obrigado novamente.